# Help! Lg v10 OS update erased entire calendar

Tags: updates, calendar, lg, operating-system

All past events, all scheduled events, gone. Also, google calendar is not available in list of calendars to sync/enable. It's not that I just failed to check a box, it's that it isn't even listed as an option to choose.

Searched for hours for reports of similar problems with solutions, found nothing. Well, I found lots of other people who also lost entire calendars, but none with solutions that worked.

Absolutely nothing I have tried has helped: reboots, resets, adding/deleting accounts, etc. 
Really, what good is a "smart" phone that won't keep a basic calendar? How many people absolutely REQUIRE an adequate appointment/schedule app on their devices?

I hated my iphone, but I'll tell ya - it never deleted a single calendar event without me expressly telling it to do so... For that matter, neither did my ancient blackberry...
Not sure whether this is an Android issue or an Lg v10 issue, but outrageously expensive phones should not be this much hassle.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug with LG that they fixed in this update. Apart from that, do you get to chose where to store calendar data? If you can, then I would recommend storing it on the SD Card

Comment: "google calendar not available in the list of apps". what does this mean?if the calendar app is not there in app 'drawer' how you know everything is gone? also you didnt mention  that you checked your google account on a PC/Laptop and it shows nothing there.